# IsSelectable steals event from onClickListener on TextView

Tags: android

I have a TextView that has the isSelectable attribute set to TRUE but i also have a onClickListener on it because. I want if a person holds on the text the text to be selected and he can copy it but if he just clicks on it i want a screen to be opened.

> ```
>             this.subtitle.setTextIsSelectable(true);
>             this.subtitle.setOnClickListener(v -> openMyScreen());
> ```

So what happens is that the selection works fine but if you click on it, the first event is consumed somewhere and only when i click for the second time it works. Does any 1 have any idea how i can fix this.

Comment: use the LongClickListener event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is, when you click it once, the textview gets focused. That's what's consuming your click event. The only work around I have been able to find is using `setOnFocusChangeListener` on the textview, then check if the texview got focused, and use that as a click event.

```
textview.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            // Handle click event
        }
    }
});
```

Please note that you will still have to use `OnClickListener` as well to handle click events post focusing